# Confirm PaymentIntent in the server side

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I'm working on a ride hailing platform where Customers pay directly to Drivers

I'm using Stripe with Standard accounts. I'm saving Customers and PaymentMethods on the Platform, so, in client side the customer choose a Payment Method and it is sent and stored in my server database

So, when a customer is going to pay, in the server side I clone the PaymentMethod to the Connected Account that will receive the payment. My server side code looks like this

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = RequestOptions.builder()
    .setStripeAccount("{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}")
    .build();

PaymentMethodCreateParams paramsClone = PaymentMethodCreateParams.builder()
    .setCustomer("cus_1")//Id of the customer in the platform
    .setPaymentMethod("payment_method_id")//One of the payment methods of the cus_1
    .build();

PaymentMethod newPaymentMethod = PaymentMethod.create(paramsClone, requestOptions);
```

Then I create a PaymentIntent

```
PaymentIntentCreateParams params = PaymentIntentCreateParams.builder()
    .setAmount(100)
    .setPaymentMethod(newPaymentMethod.getId())
    .setCurrency("usd")
    .setApplicationFeeAmount(10)
    .build();

PaymentIntent paymentIntent = PaymentIntent.create(params, requestOptions);
```

The Payment Intent is returning the stripe client secret like 'pi_1231abCD_secret_ABcD' and the status is '**requires_confirmation**'.

However, I don't want that the Customer confirms in the client side. I would like to be transparent and the customer doesn't need to take any action (like in Uber, that once the driver click in "finish ride" the payment is completed even if the passenger has the app closed)

Can someone explain how to avoid confirmation or do it automatically? Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to confirm the payment intent.  You can do this server-side using an API call like this one: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm?lang=java

You still may need to be ready to bring the user back on-session if the issuing bank requests additional authentication though.

Comment: It helped me a lot, thank you @RyanM... 

So, if the bank requests additional authentication and the user is not using the App, we have to send an email or notification to the user to follow the additional authentication steps, right? Or how you would handle it?

Comment: An email notifying your user that their bank requires some additional steps to complete the transaction with a link to your app would be a pretty good approach in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This use case is termed as Merchant Initiated Payments.

Pls ensure that you add two flag in payment_intent API

1. confirm = true
2. off_session = true

If you are processing payments for the US market, the above changes should work. If this is for European/ other markets where authentication is required pls refer this page (https://stripe.com/docs/strong-customer-authentication/sca-enforcement)